# Enviar nome do usuário na SESSION com form

Tags: php, mysql

Estou fazendo um envio de um formulário da seguinte forma:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Após enviar o vídeo, gostaria que na tabela de vídeos enviados, constasse o nome do usuário que enviou também.

Tentei com método post e get da seguinte forma:

```
$monitor = $_GET["nomecomp"];
```

**Porém aparace Undefined Index.**

Enfim, como posso puxar do php o nome de usuário da SESSION, e enviar ao mysql por meio de:

```
$sql_logar = "INSERT INTO video_monitor (titulo_video, disciplina, link_video, coment_video, arquivo, data, monitor)
      VALUES ('$nome_video', '$disciplina', '$link_video', '$coment_video', 'Nenhum arquivo', NOW(), '$monitor')";
```

Comment: A ID e nome do user estão gravados em uma session?

Comment: posta o trecho do código onde está gravado

Comment: Não gravei em uma SESSION... a única coisa que puxo é isto: <?php echo $_SESSION['nome']; ?> que é para exibir o nome do usuário que entrou..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se os dados do usuário estão gravados em variáveis na session, você pode por exemplo enviar os dados para o código que executa o insert na tabela dessa forma por exemplo:

```js
<form action="" method="post">

<!-- AQUI OS CAMPOS DO SEU FORMULÁRIO -->

<input id="id_usuario" name="venda['id_usuario']" type="hidden" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['id_usuario']; ?>">

<input id="nome_usuario" name="nome_usuario" type="hidden" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['nome_usuario']; ?>">

</form>
```

Comment: Acontece esse erro: Data too long for column 'monitor' at row 1

Comment: Defini o campo como LONGTEXT e apareceu isto: 
<br /> <b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index: nomecomp in <b>C:xampphtdocs ccmonitor.php</b> on line <b>127</b><br />

Comment: Ele não está reconhecendo o campo nomecomp do mysql no form

Comment: Consegui resolver já, obrigado!

Comment: Se puder avaliar positiva a pergunta agradeço!